# $f(X_n)\to f(x_0)\Rightarrow X_n\to x_0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $f:\mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with unique maximum $x_0\in\mathcal{X}$, i.e.,
$$
x_0 = \text{argmax}_{x\in\mathcal{X}}f(x)\quad\text{and}\quad f(x_0)>f(x)\;\forall x\in\mathcal{X}.
$$

Now, let $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a sequence of random variables in $\mathcal{X}$ such that 
$$
f(X_n)\overset{P}{\to}f(x_0).
$$
Is it true that $X_n\overset{P}{\to}x_0$?

It is true provided that $X_n\overset{P}{\to}x_*$ for some $x_*\in\mathcal{X}$. But, can I affirm that $X_n\overset{P}{\to}x_0$ without this last condition and only with the unique maximum assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Take $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = -x^2 e^{-x^2}$.

The unique maximizer of $f$ is $x_0=0$.

Let $X_n=n$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

Comment: It would be true if the $X_n$ variables were uniformly bounded, so there is an $M$ such that $||X_n(\omega)||\leq M$ for all positive integers $n$ and all outcomes $\omega$.

Comment: Can you give the proof of $X_n\overset{P}{\to}x_0$ when $X_n$ are uniformly bounded?

Comment: When I wrote that last comment I think I was assuming $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, not $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  But it is also true for $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for $\mathcal{X}$ a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A counter-example when $\mathcal{X}$ is not closed is $f:(-1,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$, with $x_0=1$ and  $X_i=-1+1/i$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

Comment: The proof for $\mathcal{X}$ closed and $||X_n(\omega)||\leq M$ for all $n, \omega$ uses that for any $\epsilon>0$ we have the maximum of the continuous function $f$ over the closed and bounded set $\mathcal{X} \cap \{x : ||x_0-x||\geq \epsilon\} \cap \{x : ||x||\leq M\}$ must be strictly lower than $f(x_0)$ (else we would have two maximizers of $f$ over $\mathcal{X}$).